# Need help displaying my Image using paint

Tags: java, image, graphics, paint, game-engine

but Ive spent several hours trying to run this code and it just isnt working. Firstly its supposed to print an image to my screen. So far it doesnt want to print my image but it will still print the rectangle and string. I have tried many things, im not even sure if it is loading the image anymore. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Im using NetBeans if that helps

```
        public class Screen extends JPanel implements Runnable {

        public Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        private Image Cat;

public Screen(Frame frame) {

        thread.start();
}
public void run(){
    System.out.println("this is running");
    loadPic();
    repaint();

        try{
        Thread.sleep(1);

    } catch(Exception e) {}
    }

public void loadPic(){
    Cat = new ImageIcon("catIcon1.png").getImage();
    System.out.println("Image Loaded!");
    repaint();
}
public void paint(Graphics g){

    g.drawString("sup tho!", 250, 250);
    g.fillRect(50,50,50,50);

    System.out.println("this works?");

          g.drawImage(Cat, 0, 0, null);
          System.out.println("Cat should be drawn");

}

}
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow! 2) `public void paint(Graphics g){` should be `@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ super.paintComponent(g);` 3) Use a Swing `Timer` for animation. 4) Don't load the image every loop. -- Just as an aside, if you based this on code you found, lose that code - it is crap.

Comment: Use standard Java naming conventions. Variable names should not start with an upper case character. "Cat" should be "cat".

Comment: I changed it to @Override public paintComponent(Graphics g){ super.paintComponent(g); and Im not doing any animation so far so I dont need to use Swing TImer yet I dont think. I also made it so it doesnt load an image every loop, but it still wont display... Why would it display rectangels and strings but not my loaded image?

Comment: @CameronRoberson It is likely that the image can't be loaded.  `ImageIcon` does that, it won't raise an error if the image failed to load.  Also, you should be using `g.drawImage(Cat, 0, 0, this);` as `ImageIcon` loads the image in the background, this way, it's possible for the panel to be notified when the image is ready to be painted.  But you should just use `ImageIO` and be done with it

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I adressed all your comments in my code. Changed the path, and put super after I loaded my image. It endeed up working. IMa go to bed now. Thanks for all the help! u guys are awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

I run your code every things seems working and the image displayed correctly 
are you sure that the image loaded? try anther image
and make sure the the image in the correct directory of your project.

Comment: Are you sure it loaded the image and not the block? Also how do i check if the image was actually loaded?